Applying a style to an image with Pandoc
I have markdown which has an icon with some text next to it:
---
title: Temp document
---

![Note icon](/note.svg)[Note]{custom-style="NoteAsideTitle"}

I convert the markdown to ODT with:
pandoc input.md --reference-doc=reference.odt -o output.odt

The text "Note" has the styling applied, but I would like to also style the image.
I guessed that my markdown would need to look something like the following:
![Note icon](/note.svg){custom-style="NoteAsideIcon"}[Note]{custom-style="NoteAsideTitle"}

I then manually edited an image in my reference document and created a style from it ("NoteAsideIcon").
However, when I generate the document, the image is not styled at all.
I also now realize that the "NoteAsideIcon" style in LibreOffice Writer doesn't resemble the direct changes I made to the image (I changed the right spacing in the "Wrap" tab, but my new style doesn't even have a "Wrap" tab.)
Does anyone know how to do this?
